# Why the @FocusState not working on WatchOS

Tags: swiftui, textfield, watchos

```
@State private var username: String = ""
@FocusState private var usernameFieldIsFocused: Bool
@State private var showUsernameTaken = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Choose a username.", text: $username)
            .focused($usernameFieldIsFocused)
        if showUsernameTaken {
            Text("That username is taken. Please choose another.")
        }
        Button("Submit") {
            showUsernameTaken = false
            if !isUserNameAvailable(username: username) {
                usernameFieldIsFocused = true
                showUsernameTaken = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

why this sample code not working on WatchOS 8.3?
It's copied from Apple Developer Documentation.

Another example is just as abnormal

```
struct LoginForm {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case username
        case password
    }

    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)

            Button("Sign In") {
                if username.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .username
                } else if password.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .password
                } else {
                    handleLogin(username, password)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate?changes=latest_minor
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link/focused(_:)?changes=latest_minor

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? could you please create a short video or gif of the problem? It will help understand the problem.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me!

Comment: I think the performance should be: when I press the button, textfield will get the focus and open the input interface. But now, after pressing the button, there is no response.

Comment: Are you sure `isUserNameAvailable` is returning the correct `Bool`? You only set your focus if it returns `false`.

Comment: Sure, I removed the IF statement and set the usernameFieldIsFocused for true. But the behavior is still the same. Are you all normal? The same is not working for another example. What did I do wrong, Please?